# What is this function that is related to the Beta function?

Tags: gamma-function

where the $\frac {\Gamma (m)\Gamma (n)}{\Gamma (m+n)}$ is [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) $B(m,n)$ then what is this function $\frac {\Gamma (m)\Gamma (n)}{\Gamma (m-n)}$?

Comment: Rather like asking "if $\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$ is a binomial coefficient then what is $\frac{(m-n)!}{m!n!}$

Answer (score 1):

If $m>n$, then

$$ \frac {\Gamma (m)\Gamma (n)}{\Gamma (m-n)}= \frac {\Gamma (m)\Gamma (n)}{\Gamma (m+n)}\frac{\Gamma(m+n)}{\Gamma(m-n)}= {\prod}_{i=0}^{n}(m-i)\beta(m,n). $$